# Programmatically Print a PDF File - Specifying Printer

Tags: python, pdf, printing

I have a requirement to print an existing PDF file from a Python script.

I need to be able to specify the printer in the script.  It's running on Windows XP.

Any ideas what I could do?

[This method](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/print.html) looks like it would work except that I cannot specify the printer:

```
win32api.ShellExecute (
  0,
  "print",
  filename,
  None,
  ".",
  0
)
```

Comment: I think you can find a suitable answer in [this similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462842/print-pdf-document-with-pythons-win32print-module)

Answer (score 3):

There's an underdocumented [`printto`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969321.aspx#class) verb which takes the **printer name** as a parameter *(enclosed in quotes if it contains spaces)*.

```
import tempfile
import win32api
import win32print

filename = tempfile.mktemp (".txt")
open (filename, "w").write ("This is a test")
win32api.ShellExecute (
  0,
  "printto",
  filename,
  '"%s"' % win32print.GetDefaultPrinter (),
  ".",
  0
)
```

*snippet from [Ja8zyjits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4693568/ja8zyjits)'s [link](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/print.html#shellexecute)*

Answer (score 1):

Looks like bluish left a comment about this but did not leave an answer.

Install Ghostprint http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/gsview/gsprint.htm

Then use the command in the question

> [Print PDF document with python's win32print module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462842/print-pdf-document-with-pythons-win32print-module)

Answer (score 1):

please refer this [link](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/print.html#shellexecute) for further details

```
import tempfile
import win32api
import win32print

filename = tempfile.mktemp (".txt")
open (filename, "w").write ("This is a test")
win32api.ShellExecute (
  0,
  "print",
  filename,
  #
  # If this is None, the default printer will
  # be used anyway.
  #
  '/d:"%s"' % win32print.GetDefaultPrinter (),
  ".",
  0
)
```

This shall work please refer the [link](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/print.html#shellexecute) provided for further details.

Comment: I have tried on numerous occasions to use the `print` verb with the `/d:` parameter to specify a different printer, but I have never gotten it to work. Using the `printto` verb with the printer name as the parameter as mentioned in what should be the accepted answer is what worked for me.