# Is there a way to allow duplex printing in excel using python?

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to find a way to configure my excel sheet to duplex printing using python.

I am currently making excel file using xlswriter but it seems there is no option for duplex printing in the document.

I could modify the excel file using some other code to allow duplex writer just before I print.

Has anyone has a way to allow duplex printing an existing document using python ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22270979/printing-in-duplexpage-a-word-document appears most people solve it via win32py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am currently making excel file using xlswriter but it seems there is no option for duplex printing in the document.

Duplex printing is a function of the printer and not the document so it cannot be controlled by XlsxWriter.