# Python silent print PDF to specific printer

Tags: python, pdf, printing

I have a PDF document and I want to print it with my python app.

I have tried the solution in [here (Print PDF document with python's win32print module?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462842/print-pdf-document-with-pythons-win32print-module) but when I install Ghostscript 9.15 that is the actual version, it has no `gsprint.exe`

The way I am using that works is with the command `os.startfile('PDFfile.pdf', "print")` but it opens default viewer (mine is Adobe Reader) and after printing it stills open, trying to kill the process with `os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM AcroRD32.exe")` kills other opened windows and I dont want it.

With the next command, it also prints, but it let the Adobe Reader opened too

```
currentprinter = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()
win32api.ShellExecute(0, "print", 'PDFfile.pdf', '/d:"%s"' % currentprinter, ".", 0)
```

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498099/silent-printing-of-a-pdf-in-python) too but they recommend using `gsprint.exe` again

Anybody has the `gsprint.exe` file or any other solution?.

**NOTE:** When I used another default program to open PDF files like Chrome or Windows Reader, I always get an Exception in the execution of the commands above `'(31, 'ShellExecute', 'A device attached to the system is not functioning.')'` or `[Error 1155] No application is associated with the specified file for this operation: 'PDFfile.pdf'` with the `startfile` command

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Finally after hours and hours of searching for the right files, i have found the answer to my problem.

You can download the GSPRINT in [HERE](http://www.mediafire.com/download/h2dpmq2frtw5psu/GSPRINT.rar)

You can download the Ghostscript GPL in [HERE](http://www.mediafire.com/download/yf52p2izc57z456/GHOSTSCRIPT.rar)

With this extracted files in your PC (Windows) you can print your PDF with this command

```
GHOSTSCRIPT_PATH = "C:\\path\\to\\GHOSTSCRIPT\\bin\\gswin32.exe"
GSPRINT_PATH = "C:\\path\\to\\GSPRINT\\gsprint.exe"

# YOU CAN PUT HERE THE NAME OF YOUR SPECIFIC PRINTER INSTEAD OF DEFAULT
currentprinter = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()

win32api.ShellExecute(0, 'open', GSPRINT_PATH, '-ghostscript "'+GHOSTSCRIPT_PATH+'" -printer "'+currentprinter+'" "PDFFile.pdf"', '.', 0)
```

The GhostScript can also be found in the Official page [HERE](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/)

I found the gsprint.exe for 64bits [HERE](http://fossies.org/linux/misc/ghost/ghostgum/gsv50w64.exe/)

I hope this helps.

Comment: gsprint.exe for 64bits  link is dead (Oct 2017)  but this one works for 32bit: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/gsview/gsprint.htm

Comment: For windows it is old link. and ubuntu or linux this package doesnot exist, this is window specific answer

Comment: This does not silently print the file - it opens a windows for a second or so and closes again!

Comment: gsprint link dead and I can't find it :(

Comment: Here is a new link for gsprint: https://fossies.org/linux/misc/old/ghost/ghostgum/

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but in case someone is looking for it here is how I fixed it.

I am using python 3.8 and gs9.52 on windows 10 64-bit and python3-ghostscript library which you can install using `pip install python3-ghostscript` I am also using pypiwin32 to get the default printer name, you can install it with pip `pip install pypiwin32`

This is the working script

```
import tempfile
import win32print
import locale
import ghostscript
import render_to_pdf

pdf = render_to_pdf('print/slip.html', context)
temp1 = tempfile.mktemp('.pdf')
f1 = open(temp1, 'ab')
f1.write(pdf)
f1.close()

args = [
        "-dPrinted", "-dBATCH", "-dNOSAFER", "-dNOPAUSE", "-dNOPROMPT"
        "-q",
        "-dNumCopies#1",
        "-sDEVICE#mswinpr2",
        f'-sOutputFile#"%printer%{win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()}"',
        f'"{temp1}"'
    ]

encoding = locale.getpreferredencoding()
args = [a.encode(encoding) for a in args]
ghostscript.Ghostscript(*args)
```

Few things to note here I am using '#' instead of '=' because for some reason it was not working with '='.

If this is not working for you try changing -sDEVICE switch to your printer type for example when I was using **HP LaserJet** it was giving me prompt so I changed my -sDEVICE to laserjet and it worked, you can get the list of device by running `gs -h` in terminal

Comment: If you already have a pdf file to print... you can replace the line `f'"{temp1}"'` with  `f'"{f}"'` where `f = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'testprint.pdf').replace('\\', '\\\\')`. Of course be sure to `import os` at the top. If you meet all these requirements, you will not need anything above `args = [...]` up to the `import ghostscript` line, seeing `import render_to_pdf` isn't defined anywhere, nor will you need to `import win32print`. Thank you for this great piece of code!

Comment: Also, `, "-dFIXEDMEDIA", "-dPSFitPage",` as additional arguments will help to center the content on the page!

Comment: Forgot to mention that Ghostscript is under GPL - which means that if you link it to use in your code or distribute it, you have to make your code open source, or available to anyone that asks for a copy of it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to silently print a pdf in the same directory as your python script without `gsprint` and without `win32api`. It allows for more GhostScript customization like choosing width/height, etc.

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    args = '"C:\\\\Program Files\\\\gs\\\\gs9.23\\\\bin\\\\gswin64c" ' \
           '-sDEVICE=mswinpr2 ' \
           '-dBATCH ' \
           '-dNOPAUSE ' \
           '-dFitPage ' \
           '-sOutputFile="%printer%myPrinterName" '
    ghostscript = args + os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'myFile.pdf').replace('\\', '\\\\')
    subprocess.call(ghostscript, shell=True)
```

If you're using the 32 bit version of GhostScript then you would use `gswin32c`

Comment: This does not silently print the file - it opens a windows for a second or so and closes again!

Comment: @bdoubleu What is the difference between `gswin64c` and `gswin64`? Thanks

Comment: 'gswin64c' is a console application ;  'gswin64' is using windows to display it's information. try the parameter -h (for help) with each executable and you will see the difference.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print specific pages and some other parameters, you should specify them in the parameters of `gsprint` as follows:

```
import win32print
import win32api

GHOSTSCRIPT_PATH = "C:\\path\\to\\GHOSTSCRIPT\\bin\\gswin32.exe"
GSPRINT_PATH = "C:\\path\\to\\GSPRINT\\gsprint.exe"

params = '-ghostscript "'+ GHOSTSCRIPT_PATH  +'" -printer "'+currentprinter+'" -from 1 -to 3 -landscape -copies 1 "1.pdf "'
print(params)

win32api.ShellExecute(0, 'open', GSPRINT_PATH, params, '.',0)
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code will block the current task

```
for i in range(10):
    currentprinter = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()
    win32api.ShellExecute(0, "print", 'PDFfile.pdf', '/d:"%s"' % currentprinter, ".", 0)
```

and killing the reader after printing help won't block the current task

```
os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM AcroRD32.exe")
```

but it will close other pdf files too.

If you can't use gsprint, use the acrobat command

```
import win32print
import subprocess
import time
pdf_file  = 'D:\d1\d1.pdf'
acrobat = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe'
name = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()
cmd = '"{}" /n /o /t "{}" "{}"'.format(acrobat, pdf_file, name)
for i in range(10)):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

It won't block the current task and close the other pdf files.

Comment: This works well for what I need, however, even after closing the window, my adobe acrobat stays open.  Is there a way to ensure that it closes as well?

Comment: try the following,cmd = '"{}" /n /o /t "{}" "{}"'.format(acrobat, file_path, printer_name)
                        proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
                        stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
                        proc.terminate()

Comment: I still can't seem to make that work.  It closes the file with the pdf, but adobe acrobat itself stays open.

Comment: try mimimize it, I won't come again I guess, For me Adobe come in task bar and won't come in opened state

Comment: Adobe flashes open the file and closes it right away, however, the Adobe program stays open in the taskbar.  Is that was you're describing?  I want to know how to completely close the adobe program.  Though, I guess that would close out any other files the user had open, which is no good.  Is there any solution that fits what I described?

Comment: I believe, adobe stays open in the task bar, we can't change it.

Answer (score 2):

Based on previous answers and other posts, i develop the following script to print `.pdf` and `.ps` from a Laravel website.

I used `python 3.9` and `Ghostscript 9.54` (for 64bits). `pywin32` and `python3-ghostscript` libs are requiered too.

```
import os
import sys
import win32print
import win32api
import ghostscript
import locale

USELESS_PRINTER = ['OneNote for Windows 10', 'OneNote (Desktop)', 'Microsoft XPS Document Writer',
                   'Microsoft Print to PDF', 'Fax']

HELP = """pyPrinter - Author: Arthur SICARD - Date: 19/05/2021
\n-help
\tDisplay this message.
\n-list [-virtual]
\tReturn list of available printer (excepted: """ + ", ".join(USELESS_PRINTER) + """)
\n-file filepath [-printer printer_name] [-virtual]
\tPrint specified file on default system printer. Use -printer to specify printer to use. Printer name must be available un -list response.
\n-batch filepath [-printer printer_name] [-virtual]
\tPrint each document specified un batch file on default system printer. Batch file must be a .txt. Each file to print must be write on its own line.
\tUse -printer to specify printer to use. Printer name must be available un -list response.
\n-virtual
\tUse this option after all other arguments to enable printing on virtual printer 'Microsoft Print to PDF'
"""


# Safe accessor to argv. Return None if index is not set
def getArgv(index):
    try:
        return (sys.argv[1:])[index]
    except:
        return None


# Return list of local printer available without "virtual printer" define in USELESS_PRINTER list.
def getAvailablePrinters():
    printers = win32print.EnumPrinters(win32print.PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL)
    printer_list = []
    for x in range(len(printers)):
        if printers[x][2] not in USELESS_PRINTER:
            printer_list.append(printers[x][2])
    return printer_list


# Return printer name to use. If -printer is set it will return this value only if value match with available
# printers list. Return a error if -printer not in list. If no printer specified, retrieve default printer and return
# its name. Sometime default printer is on USELESS_PRINTER list so first printer return by getAvailablePrinters() is
# return. If no printer is return display an error.
def getPrinter():
    default_printer = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()
    if default_printer in USELESS_PRINTER:
        if len(getAvailablePrinters()) == 0:
            print("No printer available, unable to print. Use -virtual if you want enable virtual printer.")
            sys.exit(1801)
        default_printer = getAvailablePrinters()[0]
    if getArgv(2) is not None:
        if getArgv(2) == "-printer":
            printer = getArgv(3)
            if printer in getAvailablePrinters():
                return printer
            else:
                if printer is not None:
                    print("Given printer not found. Defaut printer configured: ", default_printer)
    return default_printer


# Use GhostScript API to silent print .pdf and .ps. Use win32api to print .txt. Return a error if printing failed or
# file ext doesn't match.
def printFile(filepath):
    try:
        if os.path.splitext(filepath)[1] in [".pdf", ".ps"]:
            args = [
                "-dPrinted", "-dBATCH", "-dNOSAFER", "-dNOPAUSE", "-dNOPROMPT"
                                                                  "-q",
                "-dNumCopies#1",
                "-sDEVICE#mswinpr2",
                f'-sOutputFile#"%printer%{getPrinter()}"',
                f'"{filepath}"'
            ]

            encoding = locale.getpreferredencoding()
            args = [a.encode(encoding) for a in args]
            ghostscript.Ghostscript(*args)
        elif os.path.splitext(filepath)[1] in [".txt"]:
            # '"%s"' % enable to encapsulate string with quote
            win32api.ShellExecute(0, "printto", '"%s"' % filepath, '"%s"' % getPrinter(), ".", 0)
        return True

    except:
        print("Printing error for file: ", '"%s"' % filepath, "| Printer: ", '"%s"' % getPrinter())
        return False


def main(argv):
    if len(argv) in [1, 2, 4, 5]:
        cmd1 = getArgv(0)
        filepath = getArgv(1)

        if argv[-1] == "-virtual":
            USELESS_PRINTER.remove('Microsoft Print to PDF')

        # Batch printing mode
        if cmd1 == "-batch" and len(argv) in [2, 4, 5]:
            if not os.path.isfile(filepath) and not os.path.exists(filepath):
                print("Path provide for batch file is not a valid file path or doesn't exist.")
                sys.exit(2)
            if os.path.splitext(filepath)[1] in [".txt"]:
                with open(filepath) as fp:
                    line = fp.readline().strip('\n')
                    while line:
                        if not os.path.isfile(line) and not os.path.exists(line):
                            print("Path provide is not a valid file path or doesn't exist: ", line)
                        else:
                            printFile(line)
                        line = fp.readline().strip('\n')
                fp.close()
            else:
                print("Not supported file format for batch printing.")
                sys.exit(50)

        # Single file printing mode
        elif cmd1 == "-file" and len(argv) in [2, 4, 5]:
            if not os.path.isfile(filepath) and not os.path.exists(filepath):
                print("Path provide is not a file path.")
                sys.exit(2)
            if not printFile(filepath):
                sys.exit(1)

        # Get printers list
        elif cmd1 == "-list" and len(argv) in [1, 2]:
            for printer in getAvailablePrinters():
                print(printer)

        # Display help
        elif cmd1 == "-help" and len(argv) in [1]:
            print(HELP)
            sys.exit(0)
        else:
            print("Unknow option. Use -help to obtain more informations about supported options.")
            sys.exit(50)
    else:
        print("Wrong arguments number. Use -help to obtain more informations about supported options.")
        sys.exit(50)
    exit(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Following command explain how to use it:
`python main.py -help`

```
pyPrinter - Author: Arthur - Date: 19/05/2021

-help
    Display this message.

-list [-virtual]
    Return list of available printer (excepted: OneNote for Windows 10, OneNote (Desktop), Microsoft XPS Document Writer, Microsoft Print to PDF, Fax)

-file filepath [-printer printer_name] [-virtual]
    Print specified file on default system printer. Use -printer to specify printer to use. Printer name must be available un -list response.

-batch filepath [-printer printer_name] [-virtual]
    Print each document specified un batch file on default system printer. Batch file must be a .txt. Each file to print must be write on its own line.
    Use -printer to specify printer to use. Printer name must be available un -list response.

-virtual
    Use this option after all other arguments to enable printing on virtual printer 'Microsoft Print to PDF'
```

To print one file to printer `HP1FF6CC (HP OfficeJet Pro 6970)`

`python main.py -file "D:\my\system\path\to\file\pattern.ps" -printer "HP1FF6CC (HP OfficeJet Pro 6970)"`

To print one file to virtual printer `Microsoft Print to PDF` (generally for text purpose, paper is quickly expensive)

`python main.py -file "D:\my\system\path\to\file\pattern.ps" -printer "Microsoft Print to PDF" -virtual`

Comment: I do like this full tool using the ghostscript module. Interesting work.
Yet I tried to use your printing command by using the module - but always had issues getting the pdf filepath right.
And as the pdf file was not to be found by the ghostscript executable, a printing dialog would appear with start-page set to 0 and end-page set to 0.

Was only able to solve this issue by passing the arguments directly to the gswin64c.exe, instead of using the ghostscript module (using a subprocess.Popen())

Answer (score 2):

There is another method to send the file to printer without adobe reader also, by SumatraPDF

install SumatraPDF application and add the SumatraPDF.exe location to the path

```
# import subprocess and os
import subprocess
import os

# file path
file_name = "Document.pdf"
if file_name:
    print("exist")

# send data to the printer

try:
    subprocess.call(['SumatraPDF.exe', '-print-to', "Barcode",
                     '-print-settings', "1x", file_name])

except BaseException as msg:
    print(msg)
```

there is no need to have any adobe reader, and for every time it wont open the adobe reader to read data,
but issue is that should try on page orientation and page size,
but if those are same always for pdf seems we can change in the printer properties directly,

only to add exe path to the file path in system[image]

thats it

Comment: After fiddling around for half a day, this was the only solution I could get to work. Thank you! Note that you can also grab the portable binary and drop it in your project's root directory.

Comment: remember to replace the 'BarCode' with your printer name, and if you use the portable version it's better to provide absolute paths for the pdf file and for the exe

Answer (score 0):

So this isn't exactly silently, but it will automatically dismiss the dialog box and print anyway, also has a weird dependency on selenium that you wouldn't expect per se, but this actually worked for me since I was in a world where I wasn't allowed to download ghostscript nor could I download adobe's pdf reader. I thought it might help someone else out there, somewhere, some place, some time...

```
from selenium import webdriver
import win32com.client
import win32print
import time

def printpdf(pdf,printer):
    current_printer = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()
    win32print.SetDefaultPrinter(printer)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(pdf)
    time.sleep(1) #Adjust as necessary
    shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
    shell.SendKeys('^p')
    time.sleep(1) #Adjust as necessary
    shell.SendKeys('{ENTER}') #dismiss the print dialog box
    driver.close()
    win32print.SetDefaultPrinter(current_printer)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Adobe try this:

```
import win32api
import winreg
import subprocess
import time

def get_adobe_executable():
    with winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) as conn:
        with winreg.OpenKey(conn, r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\AcroRd32.exe', 0, winreg.KEY_READ) as hkey:
            value = winreg.QueryValue(hkey, None)
            if value:
                value = '"{}"'.format(value)
                return value.strip()
    return None

def print_pdf_file(file, printer_name=None, secs=5):
    cmd = get_adobe_executable()
    if cmd is None:
        return False
    if printer_name:
        cmd = '{} /h /t "{}" "{}"'.format(cmd, file, printer_name)
    else:
        cmd = '{} /p /h "{}"'.format(cmd, file)
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
    time.sleep(secs)
    proc.kill()
    
    return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print_pdf_file("doc.pdf") # print with default printer
    print_pdf_file("doc.pdf", "HP LaserJet Pro M102") # setting the printer name
```

`get_adobe_executable`

Get the Adobe from the registry(you can also get the print command like the one that you right click the pdf file and select Print from the menu but I wanted to just get the path then configure it according to the printer configuration)

`print_pdf_file`

If you don't set the `printer_name` variable, Adobe will print with the default printer

After executing the print command it will wait 5 seconds and then close Adobe program, Adobe it does not have command line option (as today of writing) to exit after printing the file, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/619203/453348) you can see the command line options