# How to print a turtle() window?

Tags: python, printing, tkinter, turtle-graphics, tkinter-canvas

So i have this simple turtle spiral-maker and i was wondering if there is a way to physically print off a copy of my designs that are created by the program.

Code:

```
import turtle
x= float(input("Angle: "))
y= float(input("Step: "))
scale = int(input("Scale: "))
window = turtle.Screen()
window.bgcolor("white")
turtle = turtle.Turtle()
turtle.color("black")
turtle.speed(100)
turtle.pendown()
size=0
for i in range(scale):
   size+=y
   turtle.left(x)
   turtle.forward(size)
```

For example, if the variables are:

```
x=121
y=1
scale=300
```

The program makes this:
 [image]

Is it possible to print these windows, without the user manually doing so?

Comment: You just need to print the image you posted?

Comment: Well any image that the program makes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save a screenshot of the turtle Tk canvas as a postscript file like this:

```
canvas = window.getcanvas()
canvas.postscript(file='/tmp/out.ps')
```

You could then use `subprocess` to call a print command. On unix, for example,

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['lpr', '/tmp/out.ps'])
```

---

```
import turtle
import random
import subprocess

x = float(input("Angle: "))
y = float(input("Step: "))
scale = int(input("Scale: "))
# x, y, scale = 121, 1, 300
window = turtle.Screen()
window.bgcolor("white")
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.color("black")
t.speed(100)
t.pendown()
size = 0
for i in range(scale):
    size += y
    t.left(x)
    t.forward(size)

canvas = window.getcanvas()
filename = '/tmp/out.ps'
canvas.postscript(file=filename)
subprocess.call(['lpr', filename])
turtle.mainloop()
```

---

Tip: It is better not to reassign module names to other values, as in

```
turtle = turtle.Turtle()
```

It makes it hard to call any other function from the original turtle module. Better to give the Turtle instance a new variable name, such as `t`:

```
t = turtle.Turtle()
```

Comment: I get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "T:\Desktop\Turtle.py", line 24, in <module>
    subprocess.call(['lpr', filename])
  File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 537, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 859, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 1112, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: The error is saying `filename` could not by found. Are you specifying a full absolute path?

Comment: Yep still not working even if I specify the full path

Comment: Was the postscript file successfully saved to disk? Can you view the file? Can you print it from the Windows console with `lpr /path/to/file.ps`? Knowing if any of those steps are going wrong might help us figure out what is going wrong in the Python script.

Comment: Yes the file exists but it will not print the canvas

Comment: You mean, from the Windows console, `lpr /path/to/file.ps` does not print the image?

Comment: Yes basically im pretty sure that the program creates the file but when it try to print it i don't think it can because i think it is trying to open the .ps file and i don't have a program installed to open .ps files

Comment: I don't know much about Windows. You might want to [search SuperUser](http://superuser.com/search?q=[windows]+print+command-line) for how to print postscript from the command-line.

Comment: Its really strange i tried to print using `os.startfile(filename, "print")` but that failed too!

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1464974/190597) mentions [Ghostscript for Windows](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/) which has [gsprint](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/gsview/index.htm) which appears to be able to [print postscript to windows printers](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/gsview/gsprint.htm).